# sphinx.ext.pngmath raise an error when I try a simple expression

Tags: latex, python-sphinx

I'm using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) to create the documentation of my project. I want to use the extension *sphinx.ext.pngmath* and with this little test:

```
    Returns the indefinite integral of the polynomial *poly*:
    .. math::
        \int p(x)dx
```

I got the error:

```
WARNING: inline latex u'\\int p(x)dx\n\n': latex exited with error:             
[stderr]

[stdout]
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./math.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

! LaTeX Error: File `utf8x.def' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: def)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.131 \endinput
               ^^M
No pages of output.
Transcript written on math.log.
```

I have installed the package texlive-latex-base.

Thank you,
rubik

Comment: No one? I don't understand the error!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`texlive-full` will install all the texlive packages which is indeed a bit of an overkill.

You can install just `texlive-latex-extra` to fix this particular problem.

Comment: texlive-latex-extra is not enough !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and installed the package 'texlive-full' on ubuntu. This is a bit overkill, but it fixed the problem....

Mike

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with MikTeX and found I needed to install the ucs package to get utf8x.def. Just sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem but on Windows 7, 64-bit with [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/)  and these solutions weren't relevant. MiKTeX is set to download packages as they are required and I noticed that the stderr contained "Unknown archive file size." followed by the word: "unicode" so I went into the MiKTeX package manager and installed everything with the word unicode in it. But the package manager failed with a similar *Unknown archive file size* error. I then switched to another repository mirror and installed all unicode packages. And then... everything worked!

Comment: Thanks for the info, although I cannot test it, since my problem was on linux!